# Creating an Image Icon from a local file for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, embedded-resource

So I am trying to add an image to a JLabel object which is added to a JPanel called "topPanel" which is part of a JFrame called 
"primaryWindow". I have already declared the "topPanel" and "primaryWindow". I found on other forms that you have to create a separate source folder and add the image file in that folder in order to access it and I did so.

However, when I execute the following, the image does not appear to be on the Label. I know that it has nothing to do with adding the JLabel to the panel properly because when I enter a String into the JLabel constructor, the String appears on the panel. An image however does not appear. Am I properly adding the image? I am using a mac if this helps.

```
private JLabel image = new JLabel();
image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Check.png"));
topPanel.add(image);
primaryWindow.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Your image is located where in relation to your code in the project?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: `ImageIcon` assumes that the `String` represents a local file on the file system.  Based on you example it suggests that the image is within the root directory of the working directory - It's possible that the image doesn't exist where you think it does - instead, use `ImageIO.read` to read the image, it will at least throw an exception if the image can't be read for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `BufferedImage`

```
 BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\xx\\xxx\\Check.png.jpg"));
 Image scaled = myPicture.getScaledInstance(100,70,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
 image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled));
 topPanel.add(image);
 primaryWindow.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Note that `"C:\\xx\\xxx\\Check.png.jpg"` is the path where you save Check.png.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

The ImageIcon that you passed into the setIcon method of the JLabel could be null.  Have you tried to check if it is null before calling setIcon?  If you create a "res" resource folder in the root directory of your project, you could try the following:

```
image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("res/Check.png"))));
```

Additionally, if you are using Eclipse, you should try and refresh the project directory by right clicking and pressing refresh; sometimes Eclipse doesn't register files added.

Lastly, try setting the background of the JPanel to a certain color to see if it is displaying it and make sure its width and height are not 0 (it is possible that the layout you are using changed its size).